# PhpStorm caret placement after function auto-completion

Tags: phpstorm

I want the caret to be placed inside of the braces after I hit ENTER to auto-complete a function. Right now, the caret is placed after the end brace.

How do I get the IDE to place the caret inside of the braces after auto-completion? I can't seem to find the setting.

Comment: It already does it: if function has parameters then cursor is placed inside braces; otherwise -- after them. Works like that for PHP code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER seems to work like a treat for completing the line / braces / etc. It is an extra keystroke combination but it works great.